# Appending result of HashingVectorizer at the end of previous result of HashingVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

what i want to do is incremental learning of spam filter using hashingVectorizer and tfidfTransformer in sklearn.
Here is my code-

```
for i in range(0,sz-1):

    messages_bow = HashingVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas,non_negative=True,n_features=3000).transform(final[i]['message'])
    if i==0:
        temparr=messages_bow
    else:
        temparr.append(messages_bow)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(temparr)
    messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
    spam_detector=MB.partial_fit(messages_tfidf,final[i]['label'],classes=['ham','spam'])

    messages_bow = HashingVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas,non_negative=True,n_features=3000).transform(final[i+1]['message'])
    #tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)
    messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
    predictions=spam_detector.predict(messages_tfidf)
    L=list(np.array(predictions))
    perf_measure(list(np.array(final[i+1]['label'])),L)
    val=val+accuracy_score(final[i+1]['label'],predictions)
```

final[i]['message'] contains 100 messages.I want to append result of hashingVectorizer to the previous result,so that i can use this in tfidfTransformer as hashingVectorizer is stateless and tfidfTransformer is statefull.
But i am getting following error-

```
 temparr.append(messages_bow)
 File "/home/aditya/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 525, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: append not found
```

what should i do??

Comment: can you explain more what you are looking to achieve here ?

Comment: at each iteration I want to append the new result from hashingVectorizer to the previous result,so that at each iteration I have matrix which contain results of all the previous iteration.This matrix then act as input of tfidfTransformer,which convert the matrix into normalized tf-idf representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `scikit learn HashingVectorizer`return a scipy sparse matrix you need to use `scipy.sparse.vstack`, something that will look like:

```
temparr = vstack(temparr,essages_bow)
```

Comment: thanks,it works but there is slight modification in syntax-
   `temparr = vstack((temparr,messages_bow))`